# Discarding all output from cron job

Tags: linux, cron, redhat

When creating cron jobs I've always written them like this:

```
15 0 * * * /somepath/somescript.pl > /dev/null 2>&1
```

With regards the bit at the end "> /dev/null 2>&1" which discards all stderr and stdout, I've always seen it written this way by many different professionals over many years, most of whom know linux a lot better than me. Today I found it is possible to write it more simply as:

```
15 0 * * * /somepath/somescript.pl &>/dev/null
```

This makes it slightly less unreadable. Is there any reason the second isn't in common usage? Is there any disadvantage? We are using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 mainly.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine, the only difference i know is that you can't override the file with the second method.

```
15 0 * * * /somepath/somescript.pl >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

will work

```
15 0 * * * /somepath/somescript.pl &>>/dev/null
```

won't work on Bash pre version 4

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Interestingly I am using an older version and it does work `/bin/bash --version GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: intressting it isn't working for me..:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
but it is under: GNU bash, version 4.2.39(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)